# How can I merge video with ffmpeg

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, android

How can I get the following merged video files with ffmpeg?

[image]

Please help me

***EDIT***

i Used hstack & vstack
the following error

```
06-24 17:11:39.133 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out: onFailure : WARNING: linker: /data/data/com.parksangha.videorecorder/files/ffmpeg has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.
06-24 17:11:39.133 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out: ffmpeg version n2.4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
06-24 17:11:39.143 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:   built on Oct  7 2014 15:08:46 with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
06-24 17:11:39.143 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a-neon --extra-cflags='-I/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all -mfpu=neon' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
06-24 17:11:39.143 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:   libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
06-24 17:11:39.143 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:   libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
06-24 17:11:39.143 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:   libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101
06-24 17:11:39.143 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:   libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
06-24 17:11:39.143 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:   libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
06-24 17:11:39.143 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:   libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
06-24 17:11:39.143 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:   libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
06-24 17:11:39.143 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:   libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
06-24 17:11:39.143 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out: Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/sdcard/testffmpeg/1.mp4':
06-24 17:11:39.143 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:   Metadata:
06-24 17:11:39.143 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:     major_brand     : mp42
06-24 17:11:39.143 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:     minor_version   : 0
06-24 17:11:39.143 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:     compatible_brands: isommp42
06-24 17:11:39.143 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:     creation_time   : 2016-06-23 21:21:16
06-24 17:11:39.143 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:   Duration: 00:00:05.42, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3081 kb/s
06-24 17:11:39.143 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:     Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 2949 kb/s, 30.02 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
06-24 17:11:39.143 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:     Metadata:
06-24 17:11:39.143 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:       rotate          : 90
06-24 17:11:39.143 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:       creation_time   : 2016-06-23 21:21:16
06-24 17:11:39.143 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:       handler_name    : VideoHandle
06-24 17:11:39.143 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:     Side data:
06-24 17:11:39.143 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:       displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
06-24 17:11:39.143 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:     Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 153 kb/s (default)
06-24 17:11:39.143 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:     Metadata:
06-24 17:11:39.143 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:       creation_time   : 2016-06-23 21:21:16
06-24 17:11:39.143 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:       handler_name    : SoundHandle
06-24 17:11:39.143 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out: Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/sdcard/testffmpeg/2.mp4':
06-24 17:11:39.143 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:   Metadata:
06-24 17:11:39.143 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:     major_brand     : mp42
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:     minor_version   : 0
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:     compatible_brands: isommp42
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:     creation_time   : 2016-06-23 21:21:16
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:   Duration: 00:00:05.42, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3081 kb/s
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:     Stream #1:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 2949 kb/s, 30.02 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:     Metadata:
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:       rotate          : 90
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:       creation_time   : 2016-06-23 21:21:16
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:       handler_name    : VideoHandle
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:     Side data:
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:       displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:     Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 153 kb/s (default)
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:     Metadata:
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:       creation_time   : 2016-06-23 21:21:16
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:       handler_name    : SoundHandle
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out: Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/sdcard/testffmpeg/3.mp4':
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:   Metadata:
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:     major_brand     : mp42
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:     minor_version   : 0
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:     compatible_brands: isommp42
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:     creation_time   : 2016-06-23 21:21:16
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:   Duration: 00:00:05.42, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3081 kb/s
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:     Stream #2:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 2949 kb/s, 30.02 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:     Metadata:
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:       rotate          : 90
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:       creation_time   : 2016-06-23 21:21:16
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:       handler_name    : VideoHandle
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:     Side data:
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:       displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:     Stream #2:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 153 kb/s (default)
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:     Metadata:
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:       creation_time   : 2016-06-23 21:21:16
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out:       handler_name    : SoundHandle
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out: [AVFilterGraph @ 0xb5468240] No such filter: 'hstack'
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out: Error configuring filters.
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/LOG: On Finish
06-24 17:11:39.153 14565-14565/com.parksangha.videorecorder I/System.out: onFinish
```

***EDIT***

Because of the use vstack and hstack went to the 2016 version.

And I use the following code in android:

```
String[] cmds = new String[]{"-i",video1+".mp4","-i",video2+".mp4","-i",video3+".mp4","-filter","complex","[1:v][2:v]hstack[bottom];[0:v][bottom]vstack",output+".mp4"};
```

But I got the following error:

```
06-25 03:02:36.438 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onStart
06-25 03:02:36.548 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress : ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
06-25 03:02:36.548 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :   built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
06-25 03:02:36.548 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
06-25 03:02:36.568 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :   libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
06-25 03:02:36.568 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :   libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
06-25 03:02:36.578 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :   libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
06-25 03:02:36.578 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :   libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
06-25 03:02:36.578 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :   libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
06-25 03:02:36.578 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :   libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
06-25 03:02:36.588 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :   libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
06-25 03:02:36.588 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
06-25 03:02:36.618 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress : Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/bitbox/3x1/t/mainVideo.mp4':
06-25 03:02:36.618 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :   Metadata:
06-25 03:02:36.618 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :     major_brand     : isom
06-25 03:02:36.618 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :     minor_version   : 512
06-25 03:02:36.628 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :     compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
06-25 03:02:36.628 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :     encoder         : Lavf56.4.101
06-25 03:02:36.628 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :   Duration: 00:00:00.68, start: 0.021333, bitrate: 3947 kb/s
06-25 03:02:36.628 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :     Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 902x1080, 5228 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
06-25 03:02:36.638 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :     Metadata:
06-25 03:02:36.638 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :       rotate          : 90
06-25 03:02:36.638 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :       handler_name    : VideoHandler
06-25 03:02:36.638 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :     Side data:
06-25 03:02:36.638 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :       displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
06-25 03:02:36.638 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :     Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 94 kb/s (default)
06-25 03:02:36.648 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :     Metadata:
06-25 03:02:36.648 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :       handler_name    : SoundHandler
06-25 03:02:36.648 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress : Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/bitbox/3x1/t/leftVideo.mp4':
06-25 03:02:36.648 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :   Metadata:
06-25 03:02:36.648 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :     major_brand     : isom
06-25 03:02:36.648 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :     minor_version   : 512
06-25 03:02:36.648 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :     compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
06-25 03:02:36.658 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :     encoder         : Lavf56.4.101
06-25 03:02:36.658 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :   Duration: 00:00:01.22, start: 0.021333, bitrate: 2360 kb/s
06-25 03:02:36.658 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :     Stream #1:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1440x938, 2544 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
06-25 03:02:36.658 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :     Metadata:
06-25 03:02:36.658 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :       rotate          : 90
06-25 03:02:36.658 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :       handler_name    : VideoHandler
06-25 03:02:36.658 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :     Side data:
06-25 03:02:36.658 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :       displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
06-25 03:02:36.658 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :     Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 113 kb/s (default)
06-25 03:02:36.658 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :     Metadata:
06-25 03:02:36.668 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :       handler_name    : SoundHandler
06-25 03:02:36.678 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress : Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/bitbox/3x1/t/rightVideo.mp4':
06-25 03:02:36.678 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :   Metadata:
06-25 03:02:36.688 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :     major_brand     : isom
06-25 03:02:36.688 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :     minor_version   : 512
06-25 03:02:36.688 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :     compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
06-25 03:02:36.688 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :     encoder         : Lavf56.4.101
06-25 03:02:36.688 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :   Duration: 00:00:00.99, start: 0.021333, bitrate: 5945 kb/s
06-25 03:02:36.698 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :     Stream #2:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1440x938, 6933 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
06-25 03:02:36.698 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :     Metadata:
06-25 03:02:36.698 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :       rotate          : 90
06-25 03:02:36.698 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :       handler_name    : VideoHandler
06-25 03:02:36.698 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :     Side data:
06-25 03:02:36.698 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :       displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
06-25 03:02:36.698 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :     Stream #2:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 109 kb/s (default)
06-25 03:02:36.698 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :     Metadata:
06-25 03:02:36.698 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress :       handler_name    : SoundHandler
06-25 03:02:36.708 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress : [NULL @ 0xb5460c00] Unable to find a suitable output format for '[1:v][2:v]hstack[bottom];[0:v][bottom]vstack'
06-25 03:02:36.708 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onProgress : [1:v][2:v]hstack[bottom];[0:v][bottom]vstack: Invalid argument
06-25 03:02:36.708 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onFailure : ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
06-25 03:02:36.708 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:   built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
06-25 03:02:36.708 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
06-25 03:02:36.708 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:   libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
06-25 03:02:36.708 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:   libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
06-25 03:02:36.708 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:   libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:   libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:   libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:   libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:   libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/bitbox/3x1/t/mainVideo.mp4':
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:   Metadata:
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:     major_brand     : isom
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:     minor_version   : 512
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:     compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:     encoder         : Lavf56.4.101
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:   Duration: 00:00:00.68, start: 0.021333, bitrate: 3947 kb/s
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:     Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 902x1080, 5228 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:     Metadata:
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:       rotate          : 90
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:       handler_name    : VideoHandler
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:     Side data:
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:       displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:     Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 94 kb/s (default)
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:     Metadata:
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:       handler_name    : SoundHandler
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/bitbox/3x1/t/leftVideo.mp4':
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:   Metadata:
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:     major_brand     : isom
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:     minor_version   : 512
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:     compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:     encoder         : Lavf56.4.101
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:   Duration: 00:00:01.22, start: 0.021333, bitrate: 2360 kb/s
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:     Stream #1:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1440x938, 2544 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:     Metadata:
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:       rotate          : 90
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:       handler_name    : VideoHandler
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:     Side data:
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:       displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:     Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 113 kb/s (default)
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:     Metadata:
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:       handler_name    : SoundHandler
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/bitbox/3x1/t/rightVideo.mp4':
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:   Metadata:
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:     major_brand     : isom
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:     minor_version   : 512
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:     compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:     encoder         : Lavf56.4.101
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:   Duration: 00:00:00.99, start: 0.021333, bitrate: 5945 kb/s
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:     Stream #2:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1440x938, 6933 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:     Metadata:
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:       rotate          : 90
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:       handler_name    : VideoHandler
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:     Side data:
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:       displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:     Stream #2:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 109 kb/s (default)
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:     Metadata:
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out:       handler_name    : SoundHandler
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: [NULL @ 0xb5460c00] Unable to find a suitable output format for '[1:v][2:v]hstack[bottom];[0:v][bottom]vstack'
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: [1:v][2:v]hstack[bottom];[0:v][bottom]vstack: Invalid argument
06-25 03:02:36.718 17859-17859/co.gioin.testsquarecamera I/System.out: onFinish
```

Comment: Try the link below. The example is 2x2, but I know you want one video then two smaller videos below. Explain what video resolution the entire video set should be and what video resolution Video 1, Video 2, and Video 3 are going to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

## hstack & vstack

This method uses [hstack](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hstack) to horizontally stack `video1` and `video2`, then [vstack](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#vstack) to vertically stack `video0` on top of them.

```
ffmpeg -i video0 -i video1 -i video2 -filter_complex \
"[1:v][2:v]hstack[bottom];[0:v][bottom]vstack"
output
```

## If you need to scale to match sizes

If you need to scale any of the inputs first then add the [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i video0 -i video1 -i video2 -filter_complex \
"[1:v]scale=320:-1[left]; \
 [2:v]scale=320:-1[right]; \
 [left][right]hstack[bottom]; \
 [0:v][bottom]vstack"
output
```

## Combining audio

You didn't mention audio, but if you also want to combine all audio add [amerge](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge):

```
ffmpeg -i video0 -i video1 -i video2 -filter_complex \
"[1:v][2:v]hstack[bottom];[0:v][bottom]vstack[v]; \
 [0:a][1:a][2:a]amerge=inputs=3[a]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -ac 2 \
output
```

If you only want the audio from one input then don't use amerge and simply map the audio you want, such as `-map 1:a`.

## For outdated versions: pad + overlay

Your decrepit `ffmpeg` is way too old to use the stack filters, so use [pad](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad) and [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay).

```
ffmpeg -noautorotate -i video0 -noautorotate -i video1 -noautorotate -i video2 \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]scale=1280:-1[top];[1:v]scale=640:-1[left];[2:v]scale=640:-1[right]; \
 [top]pad=iw:ih+(ih/2)[bg];[bg][left]overlay=0:overlay_h*2[bg2]; \
 [bg2][right]overlay=overlay_w:overlay_h*2[v]; \
 [0:a][1:a][2:a]amerge=inputs=3[a]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -ac 2 output
```

Comment: I use your code. 
But I did not succeed. Error to put in high places

Comment: No such filter: 'hstack'

Comment: @OmidNaji Your `ffmpeg` is too old. Why are you using 2.4.2? Why does it seem like all Android users use this old, outdated version? Where did you get it? I added a new example using pad+overlay which should work on your ancient version.

Comment: Because of the use vstack and hstack went to the 2016 version. But I got the following error: `I/System.out:       handler_name    : SoundHandler
I/System.out: [NULL @ 0xb5460c00] Unable to find a suitable output format for '[1:v][2:v]hstack[bottom];[0:v][bottom]vstack'
I/System.out: [1:v][2:v]hstack[bottom];[0:v][bottom]vstack: Invalid argument
I/System.out: onFinish`

Comment: @OmidNaji You need to show your actual command you used and the complete console output. You can update your question with this info.

Comment: tnx for your answer. i edited question and complete details

Comment: `"-filter","complex"` should be `"-filter_complex"`

Comment: thanks guys. I use this method And succeeded.
But slow operation is performed much !!!. 3-second video is required for 2 minutes !!! 
There is a way that can be done faster?

Comment: @OmidNaji You're attempting to encode HD video on a phone. Not much you can do. Add `-preset ultrafast`, try scaling the output so it is smaller, and check that the console output does not show `using cpu capabilities: none!` (that indicates a problem with your build). There may be a hardware encoding solution involving your hardware, but I have little experience with that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a mosaic out of several input videos

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20mosaic%20out%20of%20several%20input%20videos

Comment: tnx for answer. i saw [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766793/presenting-more-than-2-videos-using-ffmpeg) for 2x2. But I do not know how to make 1x2

Comment: Try to make 2x2 video first (four videos), then come back with answer to that. Then we can three video setup.